# How to attach GSocketService to non-default main-loop context?

Tags: glib, gio

Is there any way to attach GSocketService to non-default (NULL) main loop context? A was searching over API and was unable to find any "attach" function for GSocketService. Maybe there is such a function for some lower level struct contained in GSocketService, but I am unsure how it would be with emitting "incoming" signal when running in non-default main loop context.

Answer (score 0):

From `GSocketService` Docbook entry:

> The socket service runs on the main loop of the thread-default context
>   of the thread it is created in, and is not threadsafe in general.
>   However, the calls to start and stop the service are thread-safe so
>   these can be used from threads that handle incoming clients.

To change the thread default context use `g_main_context_push_thread_default/pop_thread_default`:

```
g_main_context_push_thread_default ()
```

> void                g_main_context_push_thread_default  (GMainContext
>   *context); Acquires context and sets it as the thread-default context for the current thread. This will cause certain asynchronous
>   operations (such as most gio-based I/O) which are started in this
>   thread to run under context and deliver their results to its main
>   loop, rather than running under the global default context in the main
>   thread. Note that calling this function changes the context returned
>   by g_main_context_get_thread_default(), not the one returned by
>   g_main_context_default(), so it does not affect the context used by
>   functions like g_idle_add().
>
> Normally you would call this function shortly after creating a new
>   thread, passing it a GMainContext which will be run by a GMainLoop in
>   that thread, to set a new default context for all async operations in
>   that thread. (In this case, you don't need to ever call
>   g_main_context_pop_thread_default().) In some cases however, you may
>   want to schedule a single operation in a non-default context, or
>   temporarily use a non-default context in the main thread. In that
>   case, you can wrap the call to the asynchronous operation inside a
>   g_main_context_push_thread_default() /
>   g_main_context_pop_thread_default() pair, but it is up to you to
>   ensure that no other asynchronous operations accidentally get started
>   while the non-default context is active.
>
> Beware that libraries that predate this function may not correctly
>   handle being used from a thread with a thread-default context. Eg, see
>   g_file_supports_thread_contexts().
>
> context :
>
> a GMainContext, or NULL for the global default context. [allow-none]
>   Since 2.22